# Are there any docs on the sllauncher.exe command line options?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

The sllauncher.exe has the following not very helpful usage text:

```
Usage: SLLauncher.exe [app_id] [debug] [/install:<file path to XAP>]
  [/emulate:<file path to XAP>] [/overwrite] /origin:<original app uri>
  [/uninstall] [/shortcut:<desktop|startmenu|desktop+startmenu|none>] [/pid]
```

I'm specifically interested in what the `/pid` switch does. I can't seem to find a link fully documenting sllauncher's command-line switches.

Comment: Process Id maybe?  Just guessing. Just curious about what you use this for and how it's working.  I have a SL app and have thought about using SLLaucher to launch, but never actually tried.

Comment: I don't use it for anything. I'm just curious what it does. If it does anything at all, then it might prove useful for something.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is extremely late, but I recently had the same question.  The best documentation I could find is the post [Installing Silverlight applications without the browser involved](https://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/25/using-sllauncher-for-silent-install-silverlight-application.aspx) by [Tim Heuer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/advocates/tim-heuer) of Microsoft:

> /install:"path-toXAP-File" - this is the first and points to the XAP
>   file you are wanting to install.  This might be on a network share, on
>   the CD, or in an installer.  This is required.
>
> /origin:"URI-to-origin" - this is the 'origin' of the XAP and is
>   required.  Even though you might not be using auto-update features,
>   etc. you must set this.  I actually recommend being smart about it and
>   having the XAP on a real URI endpoint as well so that your origin is
>   actually real.
>
> /shortcut:desktop+startmenu - while this is optional, it actually
>   seems silly not to include at least one – or your users will have a
>   hard time launching your application!  You can use: desktop,
>   startmenu, or desktop+startmenu (my recommendation).
>
> /overwrite - this option confirms the XAP you are installing will
>   overwrite any existing version currently there.  This is optional, but
>   again, I think you should use it.

Below that section he demonstrates `/emulate:"path-toXAP-File"` as a way to specify a previously installed XAP to launch (matched by `/origin`).

Sorry, I couldn't find anything about the `/pid` switch either.

Comment: Ah, yes, I remember this one :) But this is more of a how-to and not reference documentation. I'll probably have to wait until MS publishes the source code of SL or someone disassembles sllauncher and figures out the /pid parameter.